# Get records that have duplicate similar names as a group

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a query to get a list of records that have similar names? For example, I have a fruits table as below:

```
Id | Name 
1  | Banana
2  | Banana 2
3  | Banana
4  | Apple 
5  | Apple

DB::table('fruits')
        ->select('name', 'id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
        ->groupBy('name')
        ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
        ->get();
```

This will give me 2 groups: Banana and Apple

For the Apple group, it'll have id 4 and 5

For the Banana group, it'll have id 1 and 3 but 2 isn't included.

My question is, how do I get 2 to be included as well?

Basically a query to get duplicate records that have similar names.

Comment: don't include ID in your select, select only name and count then do a group by

Comment: @eraufi still the same, plus i dont think it matters if i include id or not.

Comment: I think you are looking for mysql's `group_concat(id)` function.

Comment: @RobBiermann no, I'm trying to get a list of records and group them by similar names

Comment: To include `banana 2`, you could group by `SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1)` so it only groups by the first word.

Comment: than in that case only count the number of id's not all for example: select('name',DB::raw('COUNT(id) as count'))

Comment: @RobBiermann what if it has to be dynamic, means there could be 'Kiwi Lemon Grape' and 'Kiwi Lemon Fruit' ?

Comment: AFAIK, you cant

Comment: @RobBiermann how about 'Kiwi Lemon' and 'Kiwi Lemon Grape' ? The 2 records are similar only the latter has the word grape in it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so based on your feedback and questions, I came up with an mysql query like so:

```
select a.id, a.name, count(distinct b.id)
from (select name, id from fruits group by name) a
join fruits b on b.name like concat(a.name, '%')
group by a.name
```

By cross joining a uniquified version of the table onto itself, matching b.name to a.name+'%', you get a relatively good result.

I tested this with a table in my db which contained substrings of other records and the result is 100% covering. This shows results that have no match as well(count = 1).

You could run it like this to only show results that have a match(count > 1):

```
select a.id, a.name, count(distinct b.id)+count(distinct a.id)
from (select name, id from fruits group by name) a
join fruits b on a.id <> b.id and b.name like concat(a.name, '%')
group by a.name
```

AFAIK, there is no nice way to convert this query to eloquent. So IMO the best way to perform the query is to do:

```
DB::select("
    select a.id, a.name, count(distinct b.id)+count(distinct a.id)
    from (select name, id from fruits group by name) a
    join fruits b on a.id <> b.id and b.name like concat(a.name, '%')
    group by a.name
");
```